# MUI DateTimePicker set custom InputFormat

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, datetimepicker

I want to set a custom InputFormat as follows

**2018-01-05 13:08:00**

Here is the sample code

```
<LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterDayjs}>
    <DateTimePicker
        renderInput={(props) => <TextField {...props} size="small" />}
        value={dayjs(myDate)}
        onChange={(value) => setDate(value)}
        minDate={dayjs(startDate)}
        maxDate={dayjs(endDate)}
    />
</LocalizationProvider>
```

How can I do that?

Comment: 13:08:00 it is hour, minutes and seconds?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this it might works, Use inputFormat props.

**inputFormat="YYYY-DD-MM HH:mm:ss**

```
<DateTimePicker
   renderInput={(props) => <TextField {...props} size="small" />}
   value={dayjs(myDate)}
   onChange={(value) => setDate(value)}
   minDate={dayjs(startDate)}
   maxDate={dayjs(endDate)}
   inputFormat="YYYY-DD-MM HH:mm:ss"
/>
```

Comment: close string in `inputFormat`

Comment: Thanks, @PrashantJangam Please upvote, if you find it correct.